# Angular 4 Stop a component from reloading

Tags: angular, typescript

I want my component to be steady. The way it works right now is that it reloads every time you go to a different page. 
But the way I want it to work is that it does not reload. 
You see I have a Marquee in the Header, and ever page it reloads. so that is not very functional.

[image]

You Can see the "header" in blue. It has a newsfeed like slider, and every time you go to another page it reloads the slider. 
So therefore i need the component to stop reloading when it goes to a different page.

**-----------------UPDATE---------------**

**code for the html**

```
    <div class="row page-header">
  <div class="col-sm-3 align-left"><img class="customer-logo" [src]="_DomSanitizationService.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('data:image/jpg;base64,'+ kioskservice.getLogo())"/></div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 align-center"><marquee direction="left" scrollamount="5" behavior="scroll">{{translationservice.getExpression("Appointment.AddEdit_PostalCodeServiceError")}}</marquee></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 align-right"><i class="far fa-clock"></i>{{ clockservice.time | date:"HH:mm" }}</div>
</div>
```

**The way the components gets called to the pages**

```
<page-header></page-header>
```

Comment: Could you share the template code where you declare your component ?

Comment: I updated it! if you have more questions ask them and ill provide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not provide any code, so I just guess you have a basic app, with a `<router-outlet>` in the app.component.html.

The purpose of that is, that anytime your app recieves a new route, the Angular Router locates a component that has a matching routing entry in the app.module for it, at  `RouterModule.forRoot(....)`

any component you render this way, will get destroyed if the route changes and a different component loads.

What you can do to prevent this:

1. insert the component into the app.component **directly**. This way it will be always shown - and you won't use the router outlet. The header is fixed in the app.component.html. You can hide it from rendering with `*ngIf` and some basic services if you still need to hide it on some routes.
2. insert the component into a different [router](https://angular.io/guide/router)

**Update:**
So your app.component.html looks like something like this:

```
<some random tags>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</some random tags>
```

change it to something like this:

```
<some random tags>
    <your-header-tag-name></your-header-tag-name>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</some random tags>
```

You can access it with @ViewChild from the app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks @ForestG, 
And how do i insert the component into the app.component directly? 
I Just need the Component to stop reloading when you go to another page.

Comment: I put my <page-header> component into the  app.component.html file. 
It is right above the <router-outlet>. 
   <page-header *ngIf="!translationservice.loading"></page-header>
But it still doesn't work

Comment: It works half! Thanks alot.
I have some pages. that still reload it tho. I cant figure out why they still reload it.
Is there an easier way to talk to you so I can show you my problem more easily lol

Comment: I am just about to call it for the day, but if you rovide your code, for instance in a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/) and your exact problem, than I am sure someone can help you out in this community. (or me next week).